# Solr field update removes the existing index values

Tags: solr, field

I have a set of fields indexed in Solr.

Existing document:

```
<doc>
   <field name="id">123</field> 
   <field name="created_by">test_user</field> 
   <field name="user_updated"/> 
</doc>
```

When I search as q=created_by:test_user I get back this document. Both "created_by" and "user_updated" are copied to "text" field.

I am trying to update a field with:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/update?commit=true -H "Content-Type: text/xml" --data-binary
'<update>
  <add>
    <doc>
      <field name="id">123</field>
      <field name="user_updated" update="set">abc</field>
    </doc>
   </add>
</update>'
```

This updates the field "user_updated" correctly and I get back this document when I search for 'q=abc' or 'q=test_user'. But existing index result for q=created_by:test_user doesn't work anymore.

Whether I am doing anything wrong here? or anyother way to get it work?

Comment: is the created_by field marked as stored ? also do you have the _version_ field in schema.xml ? check http://solr.pl/en/2012/07/09/solr-4-0-partial-documents-update/

Comment: Thanks Jayendra. It is marked as not stored. It works fine if I change the field as Stored. I am wondering I have some other dynamic fields which are just marked as Indexed but not Stored. Those fields will be affected because of an update. Is there any other way I can handle this or should I mark those fields also stored?

Comment: Added it as an answer . Accept it if it solved your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the `created_by` field marked as stored ?
also do you have the version field in schema.xml ?
check [solr-4-0-partial-documents-update](http://solr.pl/en/2012/07/09/solr-4-0-partial-documents-update).
All the fields needed to be updated should be marked as stored
Dynamic fields should not have a problem as only the fields which already exist would be updated rest would be as is